# Relation In model yii

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

Creating relation in yii modelbut getting error:

```
'hotelconfirmdata' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'HotelConfirm', 'hotel_code', array('condition'=>" hotel_type='voca_rental' AND hotel_code=ID "))
```

> Error:Property "CHasManyRelation.0" is not defined

Need Help

Answer (score 1):

The relation definition is already an array so you shouldn't wrap the other parameters in an array:

```
'hotelconfirmdata' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'HotelConfirm', 'hotel_code', 'condition' => " hotel_type='voca_rental' AND hotel_code=ID ")
```

Answer (score 0):

a detailed wiki article on it with examples http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/428/drills-search-by-a-has_many-relation-in-yii-1-1/